# Create date from Unix Timestamp ignoring timezone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

For an oData Rest service, I use Moment.js to create a date from a Unix timestamp and I'd like to ignore the timezone.
My date is "2013-12-24", which is 1387839600 in Unix seconds.

Using

```
moment("2013-12-24", "YYYY-MM-DD").toISOString()
```

results in "2013-12-23T23:00:00.000Z", since I live in GMT+1.
By the use of

```
moment.utc("2013-12-24", "YYYY-MM-DD").toISOString()
```

I get "2013-12-24T00:00:00.000Z" which is exactly what I want. I can simply remove Zulu time's "Z" at the end.

But my date's real representation is a Unix timestamp. So if I do

```
moment.utc(1387839600, "X").toISOString()
```

I always get "2013-12-23T23:00:00.000Z", but I want it to return "2013-12-24T00:00:00.000Z".

Where's my fault?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Using
moment.utc(moment("1387839600", "X").format("L"), "DD.MM.YYYY").toISOString()
works, but that seems rather complicated!?

Comment: Or just `moment(1387839600, 'X').format('YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000')`?

Comment: Thanks @robertklep, I'd like to accept your comment as the answer to my question, but unfortunately I can't promote your comment to a full answer...

Answer (score 19):

Unix timestamps, whether in seconds or milliseconds, are *always* in UTC.  The value `1387839600` is indeed 2013-12-23 at 11:00 PM UTC.  You use [sites like this one](http://www.epochconverter.com/) to verify.

If you want it to be 2013-12-24 at midnight UTC, the timestamp would be `1387843200`.

So moment is behaving correctly.  You should focus instead on your rest API and make sure it's correctly emitting UTC and not a local time value.

Also, if you just want the date portion, then don't use `.toISOString`.  Instead, use `.format`, such as:

```
moment.utc(1387843200, 'X').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Answer (score 7):

You can 'make up' your own format. Any strings that need to be copied as-is (not interpolated) should be contained within brackets.

So in your situation, this should work:

```
moment(1387839600, 'X').format('YYYY-MM-DD[T00:00:00.000]')
```

Answer (score 3):

After adjusting the onChange functionality, like

`<DateTimeField mode="date" inputFormat='MM-DD-YYYY' onChange=  {this.onChange} />`

The onChange function can look like this:

`onChange: function(value) {
    console.log({myDate: moment.utc(value, 'x').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ')});
},`

It seems the onChange value comes in as Unix ms timestamp (x) instead of Unix timestamp (X) in case that is ever a confusion.

This should print a string like `2015-07-15T15:02:00.000+00:00`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `toISOString()`. Instead use something like this:

```
moment.utc(1387839600, "X").utcOffset(1).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "[T" + moment.utc(1387839600, "X").utcOffset(1).format('HH:mm:ss.000]')
```